# Redirection Error When Accessing the wp-admin Page on a WordPress Site Hosted on GCP App Engine

Tags: wordpress, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I have a problem with my WordPress site hosted on GCP App Engine. When I try to access the wp-admin page, I first receive a 302 followed by a 301 that redirects me to the homepage.

I have already tried to deactivate my theme and all the plugins from the database, but that has not changed anything. I also added var_dumps to index.php in the wp-admin folder, but none of them are executed because the redirection happens before.
I also deleted my .htaccess file to make sure the redirection is not coming from there. Could you give me some leads to solve this problem? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the solution, in fact GAE points only to the index file, so I created a gae-app.php file which serves as a kind of router and in my app.yaml I put this file as the entrypoint

```html
<?php

/**
 * This file handles all routing for a WordPress project running on App Engine.
 * It serves up the appropriate PHP file depending on the request URI.
 *
 * @see https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php7/runtime#application_startup
 */

/**
 * Function to return a PHP file to load based on the request URI.
 *
 * @param string $full_request_uri The request URI derivded from $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'].
 */
function get_real_file_to_load($full_request_uri)
{
    $request_uri = @parse_url($full_request_uri)['path'];

    // Redirect /wp-admin to /wp-admin/ (adds a trailing slash)
    if ($request_uri === '/wp-admin') {
        header('Location: /wp-admin/');
        exit;
    }

    // Serve up "index.php" when /wp-admin/ is requested
    if ($request_uri === '/wp-admin/') {
        return '/wp-admin/index.php';
    }

    // Load the file requested if it exists
    if (is_file(__DIR__ . $request_uri)) {
        return $request_uri;
    }

    // Send everything else through index.php
    return '/index.php';
}

// fixes b/111391534
$_SERVER['HTTPS'] = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_APPENGINE_HTTPS'];

// Loads the expected WordPress framework file
// (e.g index.php, wp-admin/* or wp-login.php)
$file = get_real_file_to_load($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);

// Set the environment variables to reflect the script we're loading
// (in order to trick WordPress)
$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_URI']    = $_ENV['DOCUMENT_URI']    = $file;
$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']        = $_ENV['PHP_SELF']        = $file;
$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']     = $_ENV['SCRIPT_NAME']     = $file;
$_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'] = $_ENV['SCRIPT_FILENAME'] = __DIR__ . $file;

require __DIR__ . $file;
```

And the entrypoint in the app.yaml :

```
entrypoint: serve gae-app.php
```